# Keeping an android service alive while the application has the foreground

Tags: android, sockets, service

I have a service that is maintaining a socket connection to a game server.  The game needs frequent two way communication to the server, so this connection should be kept open as long as the app has the foreground.  However, since keeping the connection open is battery intensive we'd like to be as nice as possible and as soon as the app leaves the foreground (ie the user returns to the home screen) we would kill the connection.

This is all pretty close to working, but we're running into a couple small irritations.  Whenever the game changes Activity's (such as to the preference activity) the connection drops.  Now we could have each activity drop the connection onPause and and start up the service responsible for this, but that seems less than optimal since it will cause unnecessary dropping and reconnecting.  Binding the service stop to the onStop method also seems way less than optimal since the connection will stay alive long after the user leaves the game.

What we're looking for is a way to start up a service at some point soon after out initial activity starts and keep that service running as long as the application is in the foreground.  And as soon as the user leaves the application have the service shut down.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it to run while the app is in the foreground (i.e., one of it's activities is displayed), you don't really need a service. Make your connection manager class a singleton and count the number of activities that are using it as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/yxOzuMGlcSo/yd-pkau0zzAJ

Services in Android are used when you need to run without a UI, so not really a good fit for your use case.

Comment: That's a good point.  However, it still doesn't appear to solve the issue I'm having as far as I can tell.  The connection manager would need to startup and shutdown based on which activities are listening.  onPause on the first activity appears to be called befored before onResume on the new activity.  This would result in the connections dropping on every switch.

Comment: Right. `onStop()` however should be called when the activity is no longer visible, i.e. another one is already in the foreground so it should work. You could also delay dropping the connection for a few seconds after the last client disconnects.